# Getting multiple data from API is taking time to load in Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to use API to show data in the table, but API data is more and it's taking time to load into the view. I have used an array to store API data and display it in the view.

below is the code:

API call

```
this.getTopicList(this.chapterID).subscribe(
      (data) => {
        this.topicList = [];
        if (data !== null || data['length'] !== 0) {
          this.topicList.push(data);
        }
         this.showSpinner = false;
      },
      (error) => {
        this.showSpinner = true;
      }
```

HTML code with for loop:

```
<tr *ngFor="let topic of _sharedServices.topicList; let i = index;"
          [ngStyle]="{'border-bottom': '1px solid' +currentColor}">
          <th><span class="chapter-count" [ngStyle]="{'background-color': currentColor}">{{i+1}}</span></th>
          <td (click)="showVideo(topic.topic_name, i, topic)">
            <span class="chapter_name">
              {{ topic.topic_name }}
            </span></td>
        </tr>
```

How do I achieve this, so it loads data in view instantly?

Comment: How many rows your API return? You could evaluate a possible server side pagination, and a virtual scroll

Comment: my mistake !!! @james

Comment: @alessandro between 200 to 300 rows and can we do client-side some changes?

Comment: thanks @alessandro I have used virtual scrolling and it work like charm!!!

Answer (score 0):

Please try to implement `onPush` or `ChangeDetectionStrategy` in your component

Doing this will instruct Angular to run change detection on these components and their sub-tree only when new references are passed to them versus when data is simply mutated.

Run `this.ref.markForCheck()` or `this.ref.detectChanges()` when you update your variable and want it to reflect in html

Please check the following links for more information

https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectionStrategy

https://alligator.io/angular/change-detection-strategy/